# One solution causing issues with an unrelated one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, iis

Recently I've had a lot of trouble with a solution I've been working on so I decided to redo it from scratch.  Basically, it's an ASP.NET application and a Web Service.  I got everything to where it should be working.  It's deployed to IIS, and when I try to debug I get: "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly."

So I tried running without debugging and I get this error:

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration 
file required to service this request. Please review the specific error 
details below and modify yourconfiguration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'BrowserInfoApp' 
or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer 
than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Source Error: 

Line 57:   <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
Line 58:   <add assembly="System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
Line 59:   <add assembly="*" />

Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config    Line: 59
```

Unsure of what this line did, I tried commenting it out.  It still wouldn't let me debug on the server and this was the result of running without debugging again:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required 
to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error 
details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'BrowserInfoApp.Global'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="BrowserInfoApp.Global" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1
```

What is strange about this, is that BrowserInfoApp is completely unrelated.  It is something that I made for testing, but the solution I am using now has never referenced it or been related to it.  I started the solution I'm using now fresh, under an hour ago, so it's not a forgotten reference or anything like that.

I'm running everything on Windows XP with IIS 5.1.

So far I've tried removing the BrowserInfoApp virtual directory from IIS. If need be, I will try deleting the entire app, but I feel as if that's unecessary.

I really don't know where to go with this.  If there is more information that I could provide, please let me know and I would be glad to do so.

Edit: I've tried deleting all of BrowserInfoApp and I get the same error.

Comment: When you created the virtual directory have you made sure of the app pool under which your application is running.

Comment: As far as I know, application pools don't exist in IIS 5.1, but I'm not really clear on what you are asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: There is a reference to an assembly which is built be a later framework than the one your application is using. For Ex. your application is running under .NET1.1 and you have an assembly reference which is build using .NET 2.0. Could get it from this message above "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing  "Inherits="BrowserInfoApp.Global"" from the Global.asax file. I also uncommented "add assembly="*" /" in my web.config file.  I think I may have also had an issue with publishing to IIS (I named the site something different than the project name).

Not too sure what went wrong or why it works now, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you copy and pasted the reference to the BrowserInfoApp class when you rebuilt from scratch.  Delete the Global.asax file and then re-add it, making sure it doesn't reference that assembly, which was built in a newer version.

Comment: There is no Global.asax file in my solution, should I delete the one in BrowserInfoApp?

Answer (score 0):

Web.config files are hierarchical. Perhaps there's a web.config at a higher level of the virtual hierarchy which is referencing this other assembly.

In that case, you'll have to upgrade the applications in the higher levels of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My setup: all my web apps were created as applications in the Default Web Site in IIS. I somehow managed  to let one of my web projects in an unrelated solution create itself in the Default Web Site. So all my other solutions inherited the config settings, but they didn't have the required DLLs.